# Open camera and pass pre-filled caption in instagram for Android devices

Tags: android, instagram

It is possible to pass in a caption parameter to the camera URL hook in iOS devices, like so:

```
instagram://camera?caption=hello
```

I was wondering if there was anything equivalent for Android.

Comment: checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712465/passing-caption-to-instagram-with-android-intent-stopped-working