# Passing caption to Instagram with Android Intent Stopped Working?

Tags: android, instagram-api

I used to send an image to Instagram on Android from my app using this code :

```
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(tempFile));
```

With the latest version of Instagram the caption isn't working anymore.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or perhaps another extra is being used.

Thanks.

Comment: Same here. It appears that the EXTRA_TEXT intent disappeared from their docs :/ https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/?hl=de That would be pretty bad.

Comment: I reported the issue to Instagram. Hoping to find a solution soon.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and sending it to Instagram.

Comment: It is sad to see this missing without any info posted...

Comment: they have disabled that .. I don't know but my project that i have been working on is just useless now !! thanks Instagram.

Comment: @Alamri same here.....

Comment: @Alamri I'm thinking about sending it to the clipboard and ask the user to paste it...

Comment: @RodrigoGraça same idea came to my mind,but that's kinda annoying for the user .. isn't it ?

Comment: @Alamri Yes it is, but it looks like it will be the only way to do it....
http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

Unless we complained so much they would go back to the way it was...

Comment: @RodrigoGraça I don't know, they won't listen i guess.. this is just frustrating after all i have done developing that app ..

Comment: @Alamri I've just seen an App doing what I was saying, take a look: http://i.imgur.com/O9AqceQ.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like this feature has been removed... http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

Here is a good way to help your users:
[image: Instagram caption]